# Mocking callbacks - strange behaviour

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a module which is responsible for choosing a callback method. I want to mock method `choice`, but even though it looks like it's mocked, it still returns random results(sometimes tests pass and sometimes fail). What is the cause of this nondeterministic behaviour?

`decision.py`:

```
from numpy.random.mtrand import choice

class RandomDecision:

    def __init__(self, f_bet, f_call, f_fold):
        bet, call, fold = 0.15, 0.50, 0.35
        self.propabilities = [bet, call, fold]
        self.choices = [f_bet, f_call, f_fold]

    def decide(self, player=None, information=None):
        decision = choice(self.choices, 1, p=self.propabilities)[0]
        args = ()
        if decision == self.f_bet:
            args = self._get_random_bet(information, player),
        decision(*args)

    # some more methods...
```

Now let's try to test it

`test_decisions.py`

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from decision import RandomDecision

class TestRandomDecisions(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.fold = Mock()
    self.call = Mock()
    self.bet = Mock()
    self.rand_decision = RandomDecision(f_fold=self.fold,
                                        f_call=self.call,
                                        f_bet=self.bet)

def test_call(self):
    bet = 40
    with patch('numpy.random.mtrand.choice', side_effect=[self.call]),\
        patch('decision.RandomDecision._get_random_bet',
              return_value=bet):
        self.rand_decision.decide(Mock(), None)
        self.assertTrue(self.call.called)
```

Comment: Yeah, `patch` and `from` imports don't play well together. If you want to `patch` it, it's probably best not to `from` import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when I started playing with `patch`. The problem is that this statement is doing something slightly sneaky.

```
from numpy.random.mtrand import choice
```

It is copying the `choice` attribute from the `numpy.random.mtrand` module to the `decision` module. When you call `choice()` from the `decision` module, you're using the local copy instead of the original.

Your test is mocking the original, and your code is using its local copy, so it doesn't use the mock version.

If you change `patch('numpy.random.mtrand.choice', side_effect=[self.call])` to `patch('decision.choice', side_effect=[self.call])`, it should work.

Comment: That's it, it works like a charm! Also worth to admit that I made mistake and had to change `side_effect` to `return_value`, so it would be `patch('decision.choice', return_value=[self.call])`. Thanks for help.